# Cookie set to expire on session end cannot be prematurely 'deleted'

Tags: php, cookies

I've been testing cookie creation, amendment, and deletion, and have come across a "quirk" that I cannot seem to explain.

I can create a cookie with a 30-day expiry as normal:

```
setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

And I can then "delete" that cookie with ease:

```
setcookie("test_cookie", "", time() - 3600, "/");
```

However, the quirk comes when I create a cookie with an expiry time of `0` (i.e. will expire on browser close/session end):

```
setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value", 0, "/");
```

I am now unable to remove that cookie manually, without closing the browser! Setting it's expiry to a time in the past does nothing. What gives?

The whole page I've been using for testing, commenting out lines I'm not using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cookie Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    // setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value_updated", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    // setcookie("test_cookie", "", time() - 3600, "/");

    // setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value", 0, "/");
    // setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value_updated", 0, "/");
    setcookie("test_cookie", "", time() - 3600, "/");
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the cookie, do this:

```
setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value", 0, "/");
```

and to delete the cookie:

```
setcookie("test_cookie");
```

OR

```
setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value", 1, "/");
```

Comment: Only `setcookie("test_cookie");` seems to actually delete the cookie (well, it empties it but it's still there). However, I now cannot update this cookie again?

Comment: If you need to update the cookie again, you just re-create it.

Comment: That's what I thought... but it's not working? It stays empty?

Comment: try doing something like this: `if(empty($_COOKIE["test_cookie"])) { setcookie("test_cookie", "test_value" , time() + 3600, "/"); }`

Comment: Nah, it just sits there blank... how very odd!

Comment: A little more tinkering and I managed to get your second example to work correctly... the issues I was having in a live environment were due to a cookie having a domain parameter set, which I wasn't taking in to account. Marking as accepted.